# jQuery( elementArray) - only selects children of array items

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

jQuery's [constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) can accept an array of elements.

```
jQuery( elementArray )
```

Am I misunderstanding the usage of the elementArray parameter, or is this a jQuery bug?

Presumably, any selectors applied will apply to **all** HTMLElements that are items, or children of items, in the array. However, it appears to only select **children** of array items.

For example, in an array with the following contents, it will not match elements with the classes topLevelDiv or topLevelSpan.

```
elementArray[0] contains
    <div class="topLevelDiv">
        <span class="childSpan"></span><div class="childDiv"></div>
    </div>
elementArray[1] contains
    <span class="topLevelSpan">
        <span class="childSpan"></span>
    </span>
```

This is true whether elementArray is used as a context or as an object to wrap and call find()

```
$('div', elementArray)
// OR
$(elementArray).find('div')
```

Here is a demonstration:
http://jsfiddle.net/A49VV/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A49VV/1/ : jsFiddle the way it's meant to be used.

Comment: @mblase75: lol was thinking the same thing :)

Comment: This really does seem like the kind of question that could have been answered by **reading the documentation**.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: I believe the documentation was read and found to be confusing (notice the link in their post on the first line?).  I agree with OP on this one.

Comment: @mellamokb The documentation for `.find()` seems pretty clear to me, and not knowing what that function does is what's causing the problem.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: True, but that doesn't explain why `$('div', elementArray)` is yielding the same results.

Comment: @mellamokb No, but [this section](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) of the documentation explains that the context selector is implemented using `.find()`. "Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method, so `$('span', this)` is equivalent to `$(this).find('span')`."

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is working as expected, when you do `find` or provide the 2nd parameter for a context, you are looking *within* the elements specified for what you want. If you wanted to filter by the top-node in your elementArray you need to use the `filter` function.

Comment: From what I read on filter, it accepts a jQuery object, and not a plain array, e.g. [htmlElement, htmlElement...].

Comment: `$(elementArray)` *is* a jQuery object.  If you call `$(elementArray).filter('div')` instead of `$(elementArray).find('div')` you will find it to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery( elementArray )` creates a jQuery object that has all the elements in the array in it.  Any operation you apply to that jQuery object will be applied to all the elements in the array.

So, if you do this:

```
jQuery( elementArray ).css("color", "red");
```

it will turn the text red in all those elements.  The jQuery operation will be applied to those specific elements.  It will not be applied directly to any children of those elements.  Whether or not it affects the children depends upon what the operation is.  This is as jQuery was designed.

It isn't clear what you mean when say "any selector that is applied" because there is no selector involved when you do `jQuery( elementArray )`.

You can filter `jQuery( elementArray )` with `jQuery( elementArray ).filter(selector)` and the elements in the array that do not match the selector will then be removed from the jQuery object.

Or, you can use `.find()` as in `jQuery( elementArray ).find(selector)`.  This will look at the descendants of each element in the elementArray for descendants that match the selector and it will put all descendants that it finds into the returned new jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks. Filter and find produce opposite matching sets. `$(elementArray).find('div')` produces `[div.childDiv]`, and `$(elementArray).filter('div')` produces `[div.topLevelDiv]`. I was looking for something more like the XPath PathExpr `//` which selects 'at any level', which would combine the two sets.

Comment: @Monte, it has never been clear to me exactly what you're trying to do (and still isn't) which is why I described several different options hoping one would intersect with what you're trying to do.  If you want the union of two different selections, you can use the `.add()` method to add new elements to an existing jQuery object or combine two jQuery objects or add the results of a new selector operation to an existing jQuery object.